# How to insert UIProgressBar on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, upload, ftp, progress-bar, uialertview

I am creating an application that will upload a file to an FTP server.
During the upload I need to show a UIAlertView and within it to make a progressview indicates that the process of uploading the file ...
The UIAlertView object is very simple to do ... but I have several problems.
Is it possible to insert a ProgressBar inside a UIAlertView?
How can I increase the progress bar with the increase of the transfer of the file?
Thank you,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, starting in iOS7 the `UIAlertView` is not customizable.

You can use the default one as it comes, implement your own one, or find a 3rd party library that does it.

If you are not doing things like rotating, there are some implementations out there that may work. If you are rotating, I recommend you use the default one or create a view yourself.

Comment: I thought there is a custom content view property in UIAlertView witht the release of iOS7?

Comment: Yeah, I was there when they said it, they removed it eventually

Comment: My application starts in Landscape mode and will remain so ...
I have not found any library that takes care of this .. do you have any suggestions?
Vincenzo